# What is the coefficient of $\frac{1}{z}$ in the expansion of $\log(\frac{z}{z-1})$,valid in $\vert z\vert>1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms, power-series

> The coefficient of $\frac{1}{z}$ in the expansion of
>   $\log(\frac{z}{z-1})$,valid in $\vert z\vert>1$ is -
>
> $A.-1$
>
> $B.1$
>
> $C.-1/2$
>
> $D.1/2$

Solution:

$\log(\frac{z}{z-1})=\log(1+\frac{1}{z-1})=\frac{1}{z-1}-\frac{1}{2(z-1)^2}+\frac{1}{3(z-1)^3}+....+...$

From here i wanted to know,how to get the coefficient of $1/z$??

Comment: In your calculation, the coefficient of $\frac{1}{z-1}$ is $1$. But you are looking for the one for $\frac1z$.

Comment: Look at $\log(\frac{z-1}{z})$ and $-1/2$ is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(z) := \operatorname{Log}\left(\frac{z}{z-1}\right)$ and consider
$$
 g(\zeta) := f(\zeta^{-1}) = \operatorname{Log}\left(\frac{\zeta^{-1}}{\zeta^{-1}-1}\right) = \operatorname{Log}\left(\frac{1}{1-\zeta}\right);
$$
since $\Re\left(\frac{1}{1-\zeta}\right) = \frac{1-\Re z}{\lvert 1-\zeta \rvert^2}> 0$ whenever $\lvert \zeta \rvert < 1$, it follows that $g$ is holomorphic on the open disc $\{\zeta \in \mathbb{C} \mid \lvert \zeta \rvert < 1\}$ with power series expansion
$$
 g(\zeta) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{g^{(n)}(0)}{n!}\zeta^n
$$
absolutely convergent on $\{\zeta \in \mathbb{C} \mid \lvert \zeta \rvert < 1\}$, and hence that $f$ is holomorphic on the infinite annulus $\{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid \lvert z \rvert > 1\}$ with Laurent series expansion
$$
 f(z) = g(z^{-1}) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{g^{(n)}(0)}{n!}(z^{-1})^n = \sum_{n = -\infty}^0 \frac{g^{(\lvert n \rvert)}(0)}{\lvert n \rvert!}z^n
$$
absolutely convergent on $\{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid \lvert z \rvert > 1\}$. As a result, the desired coefficient of $z^{-1}$ is simply $g^\prime(0)$, which you can readily compute via the chain rule.

Answer (score 1):

Consider
$$
f(1/w)=\log\left(\frac{1}{1-w}\right)=-\log(1-w)=
-\sum_{k\ge1}w^k
$$
which holds for $|w|<1$. Now use $w=1/z$.