# Find the coefficient of $~\frac 1z~$ in the Laurent series expansion of $~\log\left(\frac{z}{z-1}\right)~?$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, laurent-series

> **Question:** What is the coefficient of $~\frac 1z~$ in the Laurent series expansion of $~\log\left(\frac{z}{z-1}\right)~,$ where $|z|\gt 1~?$

**My work:** Let $~f(z)=\log\left(\frac{z}{z-1}\right)~,~$ then

$$f(z)=\log\left(\frac{1}{1-1/z}\right)=\log 1-\log\left(1-\frac{1}{z}\right)=0-\left[-\frac{1}{z}-\frac{1}{2z^2}-\frac{1}{3z^3}-\cdots\right]=\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{2z^2}+\frac{1}{3z^3}+\cdots~$$
Hence the coefficient of $~\frac 1z~$ is $~1~.$

But the answer given is $-1$.

How it is true ? Where my process is incorrect ? Any one please help.

**Note:** Someone may close the question by giving the reason that it is a duplicate of [What is the coefficient of $\frac{1}{z}$ in the expansion of $\log(\frac{z}{z-1})$,valid in $\vert z\vert>1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2577153/what-is-the-coefficient-of-frac1z-in-the-expansion-of-log-fraczz-1). 
But the main fact is that it is a **proof-verification** type question. Here I want to verify where is wrong in my thinking. And also I think that my way of problem solving is **different** from the answer given there. So please help me.

Comment: You should write $\log 1 -\cdots$ and not $\log 1 +\cdots$, but what comes after is correct. The answer is $1$.

Comment: No, what comes after isn't correct: $$\log\frac1{1-\frac1z}=\log 1\color{red}-\log\left(1-\frac1z\right)=\; ...$$

Comment: @DonAntonio op did mistake with the typing, you can see, op did the right thing after that.

Comment: Perhaps the source had $\log(\frac{z}{z+1})$ and not $\log(\frac{z}{z-1})$?

Comment: Thanks @Gary and sorry for the typo. I fixed it.

Comment: @DonAntonio : excluding this typo (which I already fixed), I can't figure out what do you mean. If you think there is something wrong after that, please tell me.

Comment: @nmasanta As far as I remember, the power (Taylor) series of the natural logarithm begin with a **plus** sign...!

Comment: @DonAntonio : Yes, you are right. $$~\log(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+\cdots~,~$$ and therefore $$~\log(1-x)=-x-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}-\cdots~.$$ Is it incorrect ?

Comment: @nmasanta No, that is correct. My last comment wasn't. I missed a minus sign.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$f(z)=\log\left(\frac{1}{1-1/z}\right)=\log 1-\log\left(1-\frac{1}{z}\right)$$

We know  the series expansion for $\log (1-w) = -w - \frac{w^2}{2}-\frac{w^3}{3} \cdots, \quad |w|<1.$

$$f(z) = -\log \left(1 - \frac{1}{z} \right) = \frac{1}{z} + \frac{1}{2z^2} + \cdots, \quad |z|>1.$$

The coefficient of $\frac{1}{z}$ is $1$.

The residue at $\infty$ is $$\text{Res}_{z=\infty}f(z)= \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_C f(z) \, dz$$ where the circle $C: |z|=R$ is taken $\textit{clockwise}$.  Letting $w=1/z$,
$$\text{Res}_{z=\infty}f(z)= \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_\gamma f(1/w) \left( -\frac{1}{w^2}  \right)\, dw$$ where $\gamma: |w|=1/R$ is a circle taken in the counterclockwise direction.

The residue at $\infty$ is thus the residue at $0$ of $ -\frac{1}{z^2} f(1/z)$, so $$\text{Res}_{z=\infty} f(z) = -1.$$
Please see the comments for more discussion about the residue at infinity.

Comment: @Mark Bennet please see the very next line in op's post. He did the right thing.

Comment: @Alearner  and Mark,  hope I've addressed it ...

Comment: Thanks@mjw and sorry for the typo. I saw this in many test-series.

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: I fixed a typo, I hope you don't mind.

Comment: Ah, yes.  I don't mind.  Thank you!

Comment: It's not really a residue. This function needs a branch cut; one possibility is $[0,1]$. Now look at the coefficient of $\frac1{z-1}$ in $\log\left(\frac{z}{z-1}\right)=\log\left(1+\frac1{z-1}\right)=\frac1{z-1}-\frac1{(z-1)^2}+\dots$ If these were really residues, the integral around  the branch cut would contain two residues of $1$ and so the integral should be $4\pi i$. However, integrate either series around a large circle, and we get $2\pi i$.

Comment: Well, yes, we need a branch cut and the original function $\log z/(z-1)$ has two finite branch points, $(0,1)$, so for the series to converge for $|z|>1$, the branch cut should connect $0$ and $1$ and be contained in the unit circle.  Your suggestion is, of course, the most straightforward.  I don't follow the two residues of $1$ part.  Why two?

Comment: @robjohn, I should have written:   I don't follow the two residues of $f(z)$ at $z=1$.  Why two?

Comment: You mentioned a residue at $z=0$. This sounded as if you were talking about a singularity at $z=0$ with a residue of $1$. We can write the function also as $\frac1{z-1}-\frac1{2(z-1)^2}+\frac1{3(z-2)^3}-\dots$ and talk about a residue of $1$ at $z=1$. Now if we circle two singularities each with residue $1$ we should get an integral of $4\pi i$. However, it is not the point $z=0$ or the point $z=1$ that has a residue, but the branch cut that has a residue of $1$.

Comment: You were probably simply talking about the coefficient of $\frac1z$ as a residue, but I didn't want someone who was not as familiar with this stuff to get the wrong idea.

Comment: I am glad you brought this up and I also shouldn't stick to the wrong idea!  A residue is defined at a pole.  Can a residue also be defined for a branch cut?  In any case, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @robjohn The residue of $f(z)$ at infinity is minus the coefficient at $z^{-1}$ in the Laurent expansion of $f(z)$ around infinity (on $|z| > R$), thus $\operatorname {Res}_{z = \infty} \ln(z/(z - 1)) = -1$.

Comment: So, maybe the "answer given" was to compute the residue (at $\infty$).  In that case, even the answer was correct.

Comment: I consider the residue to be $\frac1{2\pi i}$ times whatever is left after integrating around some singularity, such as this branch cut (since we *can* integrate around this one). Usually, they are point singularities, but here it is a finite branch cut.

Comment: @robjohn It's exactly the same, except the contour is traversed in the cw direction when integrating around $\infty$. It's an equivalent definition of the residue at infinity.